# python -m to open IPython Notebook from Windows Powershell

Tags: python-2.7, powershell, pip, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I used to be able to open IPython Notebook by opening powershell and typing in `Ipython Notebook`

At some point a few months ago that didn't work and I would get the error 'IPython: The term 'IPython' is not recognized as the name of a cdmlet...'

Now to open IPython Notebook through the powershell or to use `pip install` I have to open Powershell and type `python -m IPython notebook` and `python -m pip install #package`

Why did this happen and how can I fix this?

Comment: Your PATH may have been changed. There should be an `ipython.exe` in a directory on PATH. See here for instructions on setting it: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: Either what @ThomasK said, or you underwent WMF patches and syntax changed. You can add an alias to your powershell via powershell default profiles, that way its available every time powershell is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me it ended up being a path error

somehow my path changed

once I added `'Continuum\Anaconda\Scripts'` to my path it fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

ipython is now jupyter. just run `jupyter notebook`

https://ipython.org/